# insert data in fixed length column sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert data in fixed length column but I am getting an error.

The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[zam_pcinfo](
    [Id] [decimal] identity NOT NULL,
    [employe_name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [location_id] [decimal]  NOT NULL,
    [department_id] [decimal]  NOT NULL,
    [computer_name] [nvarchar](25)  NOT NULL,
    [user_name] [nvarchar](25)  NOT NULL,
    [teamviewer_id] [nvarchar](25) NULL check (DATALENGTH(teamviewer_id) = 9),
    [lan_ip]  [nvarchar](20)  NULL,
    [policy] [nvarchar](25)  NOT NULL,
    [os] [nvarchar](25)  NOT NULL,
    [pctype] [nvarchar](25)  NOT NULL,
    [note] [nvarchar](50)   NULL,
    [password] [nvarchar](25)  NOT NULL,
    [tmngr] [bit]  NOT NULL,
    [type_user] [nvarchar] (25) Not null,
    [w-internal-mac-address] [nvarchar](50) null)
```

I am using `DATALENGTH` function for `teamviewer_id` column, and when I am trying to insert data into this column it shows this error:

> insert statement is conflict with check constraint "*nameoftheconstraint*" the conflict occurred  in database "nameofdatabase", table "nameoftable" column `teamviewer_id`

Can you help me in that? And is the check constraint is right in this situation?

Comment: What data are you trying to insert into the teamviewer_id column?  The constraint violation exception suggests that the data is not 9 characters in length.

Comment: do you need `LEN` instead?

Comment: Why do you use a VARCHAR(25) when you restrict the length to 9?

Comment: `DATALENGTH(teamviewer_id)` can never be `9`. It returns the length in bytes and each character in `nvarchar` takes 2 bytes. What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

i use `Len` instead and its work , thank you